# Lustre Filesystem: Encryption of files possible?

Tags: linux, filesystems, hpc

I am currently reviewing Lustre. Is it possible to encrypt files that are stored? I have not found any information about this.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Possibly more of a serverfault question than a stackoverflow question?  This is about how to configure some storage software, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Lustre, does not have encryption features built in. You can achieve it with other tools / configuration.

Ex: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/lustre-discuss@lists.lustre.org/msg08336.html

http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php/Architecture_-_Security#SFS_Style_Encryption_of_File_Data

You can have the OSTs encrypted. So Lustre doesnt know anything about whats happening on the disk as long as it can read and write data from those targets.

There may be other tools and utilities to encrypt disks transparently.